# Kotlin, is it possible to access the pair of a map?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

Is it possible to access the whole `Pair` of a `map`, not only the `key` or a `value`?
Let's say we have a map

> map = mapOf(Pair("Example1", 1), Pair("Example2", 2), Pair("Example3",
> 3))

I would like to access the second pair and put it into a variable, something like I would do with a list:

> val ex2 = map[1] #this would result with {"Example2", 2}

And then i would be able to access the pair's key/value like:

> ex2.key / ex2.value

More specifically, I would like to use this in my function to return a specific pair of the map.

Comment: Maps are not supposed to be queried by index. Why do you want pair at given index?

Comment: I thought about the map like for example dish with a price: Pair("Chicken", 20). I wanted to return the dish with a price selected by the user with my function, to then use in the further actions.

Comment: So you want to get the key for a given value in the map, right?

Comment: I just realized, what your'e looking for is `Destructuring Declarations`, it works with `list` however afaik, it can only be done in `map` when  iterating through it. I updated my answer and provided you a link to its official documentation

Comment: What do you mean "second pair"? There's no first or second in a map, it is by definition unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would help

```
val mapString = mutableMapOf(1 to "Person", 2 to "Animal")
val (id, creature) = 1 to mapString.getValue(1)


Log.e("MapPair", "$id, $creature")
```

prints

```
1, Person
```

or if you're iterating through the entire `map`

```
mapString.forEach {
        val (id, creature) = it.key to it.value
        Log.e("MapPair", "$id : $creature")
}
```

prints

```
1 : Person
2 : Animal
```

or using `Pair`

```
val key = 1
val pair = Pair(key, mapString.getValue(key))
Log.e("MapPair", "$pair")
```

prints

```
(1, Person)
```

or if you're iterating through the entire `map` using `Pair`

```
mapString.forEach {
        val pair = Pair(it.key, it.value)
        Log.e("MapPair", "$pair")
}
```

prints

```
(1, Person)
(2, Animal)
```

Update: For iterating through the map you can also go with [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html#example-destructuring-declarations-and-maps)

```
val mapString = mutableMapOf(1 to "Person", 2 to "Animal")

for ((key, value) in mapString) {
      Log.e("MapComponents", "$key, $value")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems like you want to fetch the key corresponding to a given value.

```kotlin
val map = mapOf("Chicken" to 20, "Egg" to 10, "Bread" to 5)
val valueToFind = 20
val key = map.toList().find { it.second == valueToFind }?.first
println(key)
```

Output:

```
Chicken
```

If the value doesn't exist, it will give `null`.